# Can I renew my authorization token in Openshift?

Tags: oauth, openshift

One annoyance I encounter in Openshift is that every day I have to login again, as my token expires.
Is there a way to somehow renew that token? Use the old token to request a new one before the old one expires?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible with openshift's built-in features.

The easiest way is to use the web console, click on your profile in the top right-hand corner and click on Copy login command.

It will generate a login token for you, which you can copy and paste to log in.

Comment: Going to the webconsole is what I am trying to avoid here.